# Laravel 5 Function name must be a string bug

Tags: php, laravel-5

I get fatal error:

> Function name must be a string

When try to `return $redirect()->to(blah blah blah`...

```
    if($act=="ban"){
        $ban_until = $request->input('ban_until');
        if(Ragnarok::temporarilyBan($account_id,$banned_by,$ban_until,$ban_reason)){
            return $redirect()->to('banlist');
        }else{
            return $redirect()->to('banlist')->withErrors('Failed to ban, database error');
        }
    }else if($act=="unban"){
        if(Ragnarok::unBan($account_id,$banned_by,$ban_reason)){
            return $redirect()->to('banlist');
        }else{
            return $redirect()->to('banlist')->withErrors('Failed to unban, database error');
        }
    }
```

Anybody face this bug?

Comment: try `redirect()->to('banlist')` without the `$`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try removing the `$` from the function as so:

```
redirect()->to('banlist');
```

PHP functions must begin with a letter or underscore, you have mistakenly added a `$` to the function.

From the PHP Docs:

> Function names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid
>   function name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any
>   number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression,
>   it would be expressed thus: [a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*.

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Answer (score 4):

`redirect()` is a function in Laravel not a variable so does not require the `$` sign.